# How do I call PBNI methods from Powerbuilder, using method ID

Tags: c++, powerbuilder

I am creating a c++ PBNI non-visual extension, calling it from powerbuilder like this :

```
 textbox1.text = string (cpp_add.f_add(integer(textbox2.text), integer(textbox3.text)))
```

`PBX_GetDescription()` has one class and two functions described this way:

```
"class pbadd from nonvisualobject \n" \
"function int f_add(int a, int b)\n" \
"function int f_add2(int a, int b)\n" \
"end class \n"
```

Header:

```
#include "pbext.h"
class pbadd : public IPBX_NonVisualObject
{
public:
    pbadd();
    virtual ~pbadd();
    PBXRESULT Invoke(
        IPB_Session   *session,
        pbobject      obj,
        pbmethodID    mid,
        PBCallInfo    *ci);

    int f_add(IPB_Session*, pbint, pbint);
    int f_add2(IPB_Session*, pbint, pbint);
    enum MethodIDs
    {
        mAdd = 1,
        mAdd2 = 2

    };

private:
    virtual void Destroy();
};
```

And the required Invoke method:

```
PBXRESULT pbadd::Invoke(IPB_Session *Session,
    pbobject obj, pbmethodID mid, PBCallInfo *ci)
{   
    if (mid == mAdd)
    {
        int sum = f_add(Session, ci->pArgs->GetAt(0)->
            GetInt(), ci->pArgs->GetAt(1)->GetInt());
        ci->returnValue->SetInt(sum);
    }
    if (mid == mAdd2)
    {
        int sum = f_add2(Session, ci->pArgs->GetAt(0)->
            GetInt(), ci->pArgs->GetAt(1)->GetInt());
        ci->returnValue->SetInt(sum+1);
    }
    return PBX_OK;
}
```

Now the problem is: I have no clue how to call second of the two methods. I am assuming I can somehow change the `pbmethod mid`, but I do not know how to do so from powerbuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was here:

```
enum MethodIDs
    {
        mAdd = 1,
        mAdd2 = 2

    };
```

The IDs are counted from 0. Correct:

```
enum MethodIDs
    {
        mAdd = 0,
        mAdd2 = 1
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you in PowerBuilder right click the library and choose 'Import PB Extension'? Doing that creates a 'shell' object that you use in your PB script and it automatically calls the Invoke method passing the method id.